# Pass php array through html to js

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, parameter-passing

I have PHP array that I need send to javascript function (for further passing thru ajax) only when a button clicked, so I came up with next idea:

html

```
<a onclick="notify('<?= json_encode($my_array); ?>','news')" >Send</a>
```

javascript function

```
function notify(array, fragment) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../example-api/blabla.php",
                data: [{name:"array", array},{name:"fragment",value:fragment}],
                success: function(data) {
                    //Succes
                },
            });
        }
```

But it doesn't work for me. Do you have any idea why?
Ot maybe you know better way than that.
Thank you in advence)

Answer (score 1):

in the php file

```
    <script>
        var array=<?=$my_array?>; 
    </script>
 <a onclick="notify(array,'news')">Send</a>
```

Also check your url path in ajax, this is possibly the mistake